Speakers are no longer working on Ubuntu 24.04.1
I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04. Unfortunately, my NZXT AP-SPKW2-EU audio speakers no longer work as expected.
To describe the situation, I only get 3 possible configurations from the settings interface, namely HiFi 2.1 channels, HiFi 5.1 channels and HiFi 7.1 channels, as opposed to what I had on Ubuntu 22.04 which included analog configurations.
On another odd phenomenon is that my right speaker is detected as the front speaker in the test panel, while my left speaker is detected as a subwoofer. In this test panel, I can get sound (the right speaker can output "front centre" and the left speaker outputs some white noise). However, I do not get any sound in any other context.
As it stands, I tried installing/updating pulseaudio and pavucontrol to no avail, which is why I post this question. If you have any idea on how to fix this, it would be very helpful.
Here are some extra information:
output for aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: SwitchMix [NZXT SwitchMix], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [LG HDR WQHD]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Audio [USB Audio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Audio [USB Audio], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Audio [USB Audio], device 2: USB Audio [USB Audio #2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Audio [USB Audio], device 3: USB Audio [USB Audio #3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

The visual I get from alasmixer alasmixer, it appears the pcm2 is set to zero... I am not sure whether this is a problem or not, but I can not change it, as opposed to all the other controls.
